# Retrieving XML in setter

Tags: c#, xml, properties

I have an object with a few items in it:

```
public class ObjectT{
  public int ValueA{
    get
    set;
  }

  public string ValueB{
    get;set;
  }

  public int Description{
    get{
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"xmldocument.xml");
      return (string)doc.Elements("test").Single(t => t.Element(ValueB).Value);
  }
}
```

The Linq might not be perfect, but well, you'll get the idea. I'm reading the description from the xml, based on the other properties in the class. However, I dont like how I have to read from the xml all the time. Imagine I want to make 1000 of these objects, with 100 of different Description values. I'd have to make 1000 reads to the XML file.

Is there a better (more faster) way to do this.

**use case**

What I want to do is the following

```
ObjectT t = new ObjectT();
t.ValueA = 1;
string test = t.Description;

ObjectT t1 = new ObjectT;
t.ValueA = 2;
string test2 = t.Description;

...
```

So I want to reduce the IO to the xml, because I want to create a load of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to have thousands of these objects that read from this XML document. But you don't want to reload that XML document over and over again.

So write a static wrapper class around that XML document that loads it once. Provide a single method that retrieves the desired value, and it reads the data from the in-memory cache of the XML document.

Your ObjectT.Description property then invokes that method to get the data. Since the wrapper class is static, only one instance of it is created, and all instances of your ObjectT will use it. Further, the XML document is only loaded once.

Answer (score 2):

Several things come to mind:

- To reduce IO, read the XML file once, when initializing the class.
- Create a `Dictionary<string,int>` to hold the value for each description value and use that as a cache.

---

```
XDocument doc;
Dictionary<string,int> dict;

public myObject()
{
  doc = XDocument.Load(@"xmldocument.xml");
  dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
}

public int Description{
 get{
  if(!dict.ContainsKey(ValueB))
    dict.Add( ValueB, 
              (int)doc.Elements("test").Single(t => t.Element(ValueB).Value));

  return dict[ValueB];
  }
}
```

Comment: But, what I want to do (sorry it wasn't clear in my question), is that I want to create like 1000 of those objects.

Comment: @Timo Willemsen - I would reconsider a design that requires loading an XML file thousands of times.

Comment: TryGetValue() would be a little nicer here

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
public class Object{

static XDocument doc;
static LoadXml()
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(@"xmldocument.xml");
}

  public int ValueA{
    get
    set;
  }

  public string ValueB{
    get;set;
  }

  public int Description{
    get{
      return (string)doc.Elements("test").Single(t => t.Element(ValueB).Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i've added my question a bit to make it more clear. I want to create a load of these objects. So on every object I make, I now have to load in the XML.

Comment: Further, it's a risky idea to load an XML document in a constructor. If the operation fails, the constructor throws. Throwing in a constructor is a Very Bad Idea™.

Comment: @Timo I have addressed the concernes you mentioned in my comments after the code, but now I revised the code itself to further convey my idea. @Mike that depends on the situation, for instance TcpClient can throw from some of its ctor overloads. In any case I've revised the code to make everyone happy (hopefully) :)

Answer (score 0):

At least you can keep your documented loaded while you are creating your objects.